# Cucumber + Selenium - How to count the number of rows in a table?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

Does anyone know a quick way to count the number of entries in a table using Ruby, Cucumber & Selenium?

The table is fairly basic, I want to count the number of  rows:

```
<table id="product_container">
 <tr>
   <th>Product Name</th>
   <th>Qty In Stock</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>...</td>
   <td>...</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
page.should have_css "#product_container tr", :count => number_of_rows.to_i
```

Answer (score 2):

The following step definition should work with Capybara.

```
Then /^I should have (\d+) table rows$/ do |number_of_rows|
  actual_number = page.all('#product_container tr').size
  actual_order.should == number_of_rows
end
```

Usage:

```
Then I should have 10 table rows
```

The [page.all documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method).

Answer (score 2):

I always use [getXpathCount()](http://www.seleniumwiki.com/tag/getxpathcount/) (Selenium method) in such situation and it works fine :)
In PHP:

```
$rowsCount = $this->getXpathCount("//table[@id='product_container']/tr");
```

And if you don't want to count header rows, you should edit the table as:

```
<table id="product_container">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Qty In Stock</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can get the products count:

```
$rowsCount = $this->getXpathCount("//table[@id='product_container']/tbody/tr");
```